# How to customize inserted divs of contentEditable on line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have ***`generate_uuid()`*** function that generates unique ids (originally retrieved from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/3503851)):

```
function generate_uuid() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}
```

I have *`contentEditable`* `div`:

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.<div>
</div>
```

When I add a new line to the text content, the html code becomes:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.<div>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">New line 1.</div>
</div>
```

As we notice, new `div` is identical to the previously existing `div`.

When I add more lines, the html code becomes:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.<div>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">New line 1.</div>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">New line 2.</div>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">New line 3.</div>
</div>
```

The same, new `div`s are identical to the previously existing `div`.

How could I customize the newly inserted `div`s each time the user hits a line break? I want to make the `id` attribute for a newly inserted `div` be generated by the `generate_uuid()` function. Something like this should be the result:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.<div>
  <div id="0b0e3518-1fb2-43e4-9160-6563ac0f82be">New line 1.</div>
  <div id="57d399c6-afa0-42ae-83c2-d6d7937f22d3">New line 2.</div>
  <div id="1fe51cac-bb79-47e2-bd95-e813b33e29aa">New line 3.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Does it need to be a guid, or just a unique number?

Comment: @Bibberty it needs to be any good standard of generating a unique number, so guid was my choice. As my app is expected to have many elements to be generated in different scenarios and each should have a unique id.

Comment: Ticks would work.

Comment: But jo_va has solved it nicely for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when a child is added and generate a dynamic id:

```js
function uuid() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}

function subscriber(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => node.id = uuid());
    console.clear();
    console.log([...mutation.target.children].map(x => x.id));
  });
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(subscriber);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]'), { childList: true });
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks jo, nice use of the observer.