# How to make indentation move current div as a child of the one preceding it in contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, mutation-observers, mutation

I have this contentEditable code:

```js
function uuid() { // to generate uuid
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}

// ---------------------------------

// observing any div addition to conentEditable div in order to assign new uuid for added div
  function subscriber(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => node.id = uuid());
      console.clear();
      console.log([...mutation.target.children].map(x => x.id));
    });
  }

  const observer = new MutationObserver(subscriber);
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]'), { childList: true });

// ---------------------------------

// Assigning tab key shortcut
  document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]').onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 9) { 
      e.preventDefault();  // this will prevent us from tabbing out of the editor
      document.execCommand('styleWithCSS',true,null);
      document.execCommand('indent',true,null);
    }
  };
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.<div>
</div>
```

The code sets new uuid for every newly created element within the contentEditable on line break. The MutationObserver code was originally mentioned in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052982/3503851).

To illustrate what I want to do, I'll explain this ***example***:
Let's say I typed:

> Edit text content here.
>   New line 1.
>   New line 2.
>   New line 3.

Then, I will have the original html code like this:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.</div>
  <div id="0b0e3518-1fb2-43e4-9160-6563ac0f82be">New line 1.</div>
  <div id="57d399c6-afa0-42ae-83c2-d6d7937f22d3">New line 2.</div>
  <div id="1fe51cac-bb79-47e2-bd95-e813b33e29aa">New line 3.</div>
</div>
```

Now when cursor being on `New line 2`, and I press the *tab key*, the line will be indented and the view of the contentEditable will be like this:

> Edit text content here.
>   New line 1.
>   **. . .** New line 2.
>   New line 3.

and the original html code will be like this:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.</div>
  <div id="0b0e3518-1fb2-43e4-9160-6563ac0f82be">New line 1.</div>
  <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;" id="a1badbcd-be93-4193-b73f-807d619393b5">
    <div id="57d399c6-afa0-42ae-83c2-d6d7937f22d3">New line 2.</div>
  </blockquote>
  <div id="1fe51cac-bb79-47e2-bd95-e813b33e29aa">New line 3.</div>
</div>
```

I don't want to make indentation like this, with creating `blockquote`.
Instead, I want it to move the active `div` to be a child of the preceding one like this:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.</div>
  <div id="0b0e3518-1fb2-43e4-9160-6563ac0f82be">New line 1.
    <div id="57d399c6-afa0-42ae-83c2-d6d7937f22d3" style="margin: 0 0 0 40px;>New line 2.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="1fe51cac-bb79-47e2-bd95-e813b33e29aa">New line 3.</div>
</div>
```

And I want it when I intend more like this:

> Edit text content here.
>   New line 1.
>   **. . . . . . . . .** New line 2.
>   New line 3.

, the html code becomes:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <div id="48b62163-9f3b-4b20-8dad-dc99e27e1243">Edit text content here.</div>
  <div id="0b0e3518-1fb2-43e4-9160-6563ac0f82be">New line 1.
    <div id="57d399c6-afa0-42ae-83c2-d6d7937f22d3" style="margin: 0 0 0 120px;>New line 2.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="1fe51cac-bb79-47e2-bd95-e813b33e29aa">New line 3.</div>
</div>
```

I've thoughts to approach this to make the code check if there's a preceding `div` element, if so, it should make the active `div` element to be its child. Also the indentation styling will be added to the active `div` element.
 I'll play with `window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode` a little and post my solution once I finish writing it. However, I hope there's some more efficient way.